# iMessage help! my imessage has been hacked

Tags: iphone, mac, macbook-pro, messages

My brother has checked all my past iMessages on his mac from my iPhone that have been deleted. How is that possible? Is there away there any way my iMessages can be permanently deleted so they cant be read? How can I keep him from viewing my messages? Is he hacking me?

Comment: Were they messages you sent to him? If so than there isn't anything you can do about it.

Likewise, if you are backing up you phone on his machine, he'll have access to the backups, which I presume save old text messages.

Comment: We're not the best place for urgent tech support questions, but someone might be able to help. Have you reached out to Apple or tried to understand how iMessage works? We have a guide on [ask] that might help you take the first step and let us know what one item you need help understanding or getting clarified to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you fear someone is hacking your account, you'll want to go to your Apple ID and reset the password.

- https://appleid.apple.com/

If you have forgotten or lost your password, you can also reset it:

- https://iforgot.apple.com/

Once you are in to the first site, be sure to check the additional email addresses and contact information should any of that be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your Apple ID is being shared between your iPhone and your brother's Mac.  I've seen people share their Apple IDs inside their families because they want to share content or apps before; it's a practice I don't recommend.

When you have additional devices registered with iMessage like that, the entire conversations will be synchronized to both the iPhone and the Mac and—I just verified this, because I wasn't sure—deleting the messages from the iPhone does *not* delete them from the Messages application on OS X.

To prevent your iMessages from continuing to appear on the Mac, you will have to deregister the Mac.  I believe you can do this by visiting [My Support Profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com/), logging in with your Apple ID, clicking the Mac which should appear in the list, and clicking Unregister.

It is probably also a good idea to change your Apple ID password.